# iPad mini vs iPod touch 5g for developing

Tags: ipad, ios, ipod-touch

I want to develop for iOS and I want to do some real testing of my apps on the cheapest device.

Looking at the hardware they are the same except for the screen. They are both IPS but the iPod has a retina resolution.

Here are my concerns: with the iPod touch I'm sure that my apps will run well on the iPhone 5, with the iPad mini I don't know if it will be fit to test for the Retina displays in both the 4th Gen iPad and iPhone 5.

Will one of them be better for testing apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it makes sense to go for the iPad mini. This is because you can simultaneously test both iPhone AND iPad apps. The iPad mini will run iPhone-only apps in a reduced-screen screen mode, and will run iPad apps as normal. An iPod touch will only run iPhone-specific apps.

Comment: My concern is about image resolution, can I test an app with images for the iPad retina resolution on the iPad mini? I know that the iPad mini has enough resolution for apps which target the iPhone 5 but not for the iPad retina.

Comment: Unfortunately, you won't be able to test for a retina resolution on anything but a retina iPad (3rd gen+). You can, however, use the iOS simulator to get a rough idea of whether your app is retina ready or not

Comment: @Redandwhite I found this question by google. It seems that ipad mini is a better choice for me,too. I used to be really concerned about the development of Iphone apps on it. It is not only available for development. Although it is only a little more expensive, I can views the notes on the train and writing my notes in the lesson.